# Intel TBB - Eclipse reports multiple build errors

Tags: c++, intel, tbb

I'm using Eclipse CDT. I downloaded 4.1 for windows.

I added the include folder to my project by going to my project's properties, then adding the folder in C/C++ General >> Paths and Symbols >> Includes.

I added an include to the make file.

Unfortunately I am receiving build errors.

```
#error Unsupported machine word size.

â€˜__TBB_CompareAndSwapWâ€™ was not declared in this scope

incomplete type â€˜tbb::internal::machine_load_store_relaxed<int, 4u>â€™ 
    used in nested name specifier

there are no arguments to â€˜__TBB_CompareAndSwapWâ€™ that depend on a template      
    parameter, so a declaration of â€˜__TBB_CompareAndSwapWâ€™ must be available
```

What can I do to help myself?

Answer (score 1):

"#error Unsupported machine word size." appear then TBB unable to recognize compiler being used , or known compiler used in unsupported configuration. E.g. for 32 bit mingw -march=i686 or higher is needed.